# Boost::gregorian and leap years

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I'm writing a code where I use only boost libraries as prerequisites.

I need a class to handle datetime values and operations (add and subtract years, months, hours, etc.), so I picked the gregorian date as an option.

But, when I handle days in leap years, some surprises appear. There is a piece of an example code:

```
int main()
{
  boost::gregorian::date d1(2000,1,1);
  boost::gregorian::days ds(118);

  boost::gregorian::date d2 = d1 + ds;

  std::cout << boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string(d1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::gregorian::to_iso_extended_string(d2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

Output:
2000-01-01
2000-04-28 (should be 2000-04-27)
```

Is there an option for this issue? In the manual page, the boost warning about "lead to unexpected results..."

Comment: Why should the result be 27 Apr? 118 days after 1 Jan 2000 is 28 Apr 2000.

Comment: Actually your answer is correct. The code we were testing used to do an extra operation in datetime and subtract one day, for rounding purposes, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's correct as it is:

```
for a in {1..118}; do echo -n "+$a days: "; date --rfc-2822 -d"2000-01-01 +$a days"; done
```

prints

shows I see no anomalies around the leap date:

```
+1 days: Sun, 02 Jan 2000 00:00:00 +0100
+2 days: Mon, 03 Jan 2000 00:00:00 +0100
...
+57 days: Sun, 27 Feb 2000 00:00:00 +0100
+58 days: Mon, 28 Feb 2000 00:00:00 +0100
+59 days: Tue, 29 Feb 2000 00:00:00 +0100
+60 days: Wed, 01 Mar 2000 00:00:00 +0100
...
+116 days: Wed, 26 Apr 2000 00:00:00 +0200
+117 days: Thu, 27 Apr 2000 00:00:00 +0200
+118 days: Fri, 28 Apr 2000 00:00:00 +0200
```

Comment: Actually your answer is correct. The code we were testing used to do an extra operation in datetime and subtract one day, for rounding purposes, thanks.